# Saving error message and stack on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've designed a website that works through my own PC.

I set the IIS to work with Custom Errors in case user ran into some unknown exception.

I've also added a check that the error page will e-mail me whenever it found an error.

Can I somehow get the error information (Stack and description) from the error page?

Comment: Is this a commercial for the site or a real question?

Comment: Real question. Don't understand the comment.

Comment: I believe the comment is because the site's address has no relevance to the question; if the kink *is* relevant, please spell out why.

Comment: Just thought responders can look at the error page itself on the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encourages you to use Open Source library out there that provided functional need. My recommendation is [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

With a few line of settings in your web.config, you will all set. result screen looks like this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://elmah.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/homeshot.png))</sub>

Comment: Looks great. I was hoping to not use ANOTHER library in my project though. If there's a lighter solution - its preferable.

Comment: It is very lightweight especially use of SQLite. rather than reinvent the wheel. this should take your 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASP.NET Health monitoring.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998306.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Catch any errors that might be thrown and write them to the event log.

```
EventLog Logger = new EventLog();
Logger.Source = "ApplictionNme";

Logger.WriteEntry("Writing to event log.");
```

Comment: No problem writing to the EventLog, it actually happens automatically.

I just wish that everytime it writes to the event log, I'll know what he writes and e-mail/SMS it to me.